Novel about a spy infiltrating a highly advanced civilization on a world hidden by nanites
I read a novel about a spy being sent to investigate a mysterious planet covered by impenetrable grey fog. What he discovers is an advanced human civilization with technology that far outmatches the rest of known space; the spy is almost immediately discovered and most of the book is him being shown around the planet to see its utopian society and the various technologies they've developed.
I remember, specifically, that the planet had intercontinental vaccuum trains (and I believe it was published before Musk popularized the concept in 2013?) that maintained their seals using selective force fields of some sort.
The mysterious grey fog that blocked all attempts to study the surface of the planet from a distance turned out to be a utility fog of distributed nanites.
It's possible that the advanced state of the world was attributed to some sort of time manipulation, and that it was settled by people from the future?
At the end of the book they load the spy onto a little shuttle and use some sort of tesseract wormhole technology to instantaneously transport him into space so he could be retrieved by his handlers and tell them not to interfere with the world.
Does anyone recognize this book and know what it was called?

When did you read this?  Had it been recently published, or was it older?  Physical book or e-book?

I bought it as a brand-new paperback somewhere since 2011, I'd reckon? I know that it was my first exposure to the idea of a vacuum train and that when everyone started talking about the Hyperloop I thought of this book.

Note that the idea of intercontinental tubes dates back to 1895 (though not in a vacuum) and passenger vacuum tubes date back at least to 1932.  The combination - an intercontinental vacuum tube system - dates at least from 1976.

The appearance of the vacuum train is mostly notable because it helps me place when I would have read the book as "before the Hyperloop became a popular talking point".

Sounds like Haze by L.E. Modesitt Jr.
Summary from GoodReads:
What lies beneath the millions of orbiting nanotech satellites that shroud the world called Haze? Major Keir Roget’s mission is to make planetfall in secret, find out, and report back to his superiors in the Federation, the Chinese-dominated government that rules Earth and the colonized planets.
For all his effectiveness as a security agent, Roget is troubled by memories of an earlier mission. When he was assigned to covert duty in the Noram backcountry town of St. George, he not only discovered that the long-standing Saint culture was neither as backward nor as harmless as his superiors believed, but he barely emerged with his life and sanity whole. Now, scouting Haze, he finds a culture seemingly familiar, yet frighteningly alien, with hints of a technology far superior to that of the Federation. Yet he is not certain how much of what he sees is real—or how to convey a danger he cannot even prove to his superiors, if he can escape Haze.
